# iGIS failed to load shapefile?

Tags: shapefile, coordinate-system, igis

I am using iGIS for iPAD
When I try importing one particular shapefile it gives me an error(see attached pic) saying I have the wrong projection.  It is the same one I use on my other 10shapefiles that load just fine.
I'm assuming it is something wrong with the shapefile since all the other ones work.  I use the same process and rechecked it many times on all, this is the only one that gives me the error.

iGIS support has went dark.  They are no help.
Does anyone that uses iGIS seen this error before and could they resolve the issue?

[image]

Comment: What sort of assistance do need?  (Please add a question to your Question)

Comment: Since both igis question we currently have on this site are unanswered, it seems unlikely that we have many users of the app here. You could still try sharing sample data: both one that loads ok and one that doesn't and maybe someone can spot a potential issue.

Comment: I will try to do that

Comment: Is there a way to attach a file to my question?

Comment: This is solved.  I had to run the check geometry tool and then repair tool.  There was some null values.  It worked after that.   It always worked in Arcmap but never in iGIS app.  Now works in both

Answer (score 1):

Answer taken from the comments:

> This is solved. I had to run the check geometry tool and then repair
>   tool. There was some null values. It worked after that. It always
>   worked in Arcmap but never in iGIS app. Now works in both – Michael
>   Heyroth Sep 2 '15 at 14:48